# Why do I receive an error when adding a namespace over a module?

Tags: types, module, f#, namespaces

I am receiving an error when I declare a namespace over an existing module.

**Error:**

> Unexpected start of structured construct in definition. Expected '='
>   or other token.

**Note, I'm just adding a namespace:**

```
namespace ManageModules
```

Without the namespace, the code compiles.

**Code:**

```
namespace ManageModules
module CreateModule.UILogic

open System.Windows.Input // Error is referenced here...
open UILogic.State
open UILogic.Interaction
open ManageModule.Entities
open System.Collections.ObjectModel

type CreationViewModel() =
    inherit ViewModelBase()

    let mutable (_modules:Module ObservableCollection) = ObservableCollection()

    member this.Modules
        with get()      = _modules
        and set(value)  = _modules <- value

    member this.Add moduleItem = 
        _modules.Add(moduleItem)
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out on your own. In your answer you did not say why the `=` works. The namespace/module thing still throws me at times even to this day. Take a few hours to better understand the reasons otherwise this problem will eat up more time in the future than a few hours now on the side learning about it in more detail. In other words you can pay a little time now or keep paying time over and over which will be a lot more time latter.

Comment: See: [Organizing functions](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/organizing-functions/) and [Organizing modules in a project](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part3/)

Comment: Yea. That's what I referenced when I discovered the solution. Thx.

Comment: I'm just adding the links more for my use. When you ask questions they are more to the point and typically give all the info needed which makes them great as reference questions. Since I plan to refer back your [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/492701/scott-nimrod) I am also leaving bread crumbs to the other details for others that may follow a link back to them. You are doing great!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of module declarations:  top level module declarations and local module declarations.

Top level module declarations are declared with the syntax:

```
module [accessibility-modifier] [qualified-namespace.]module-name
```

Local module declarations are declared with

```
module [accessibility-modifier] module-name =
```

Top level module declarations must appear as the first statement in the file and the module then includes everything within that file.  By contrast, you can have multiple local module declarations.

Notice that while top-level declarations also let you optionally add `.` to supply a qualifying namespace, you can't use `.`s in local module declarations although you can nest local modules.

In your case, since your module declaration doesn't appear at the start of the file, you must write:

```
namespace ManageModules
module CreateModule =
    ...
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233221.aspx for more details.

Comment: Yea... I just figured it out. I'll still give you credit though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when I provide a namespace over a module, I need to append an equal operator to my module declaration.

```
namespace ManageModules
module CreateModule =
```

**Code:**

```
namespace ManageModules
module CreateModule =

    open System.Windows.Input
    open UILogic.State
    open UILogic.Interaction
    open ManageModule.Entities
    open System.Collections.ObjectModel

    type CreationViewModel() =
        inherit ViewModelBase()

        let mutable (_modules:Module ObservableCollection) = ObservableCollection()

        member this.Modules
            with get()      = _modules
            and set(value)  = _modules <- value

        member this.Add moduleItem = 
            _modules.Add(moduleItem)
```